# Remove extra space in File Explorer for Windows 10 v1709

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-v1709

I upgraded to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update and in This PC, there is some extra space when in the Tile view. How do I remove it? I do have a touch/pen PC and I do expect the checkboxes.

Screenshot with obligatory freehand circles.

[image]

Comment: are you running in tablet mode?

Comment: @magicandre1981 nope

Comment: ok, I've installed 1709 in a VM and see the same, but those this really hurt you that much? send it in feedback hub to Microsoft.

Comment: [according to the german website deskmodder](https://www.deskmodder.de/blog/2017/10/16/windows-10-1709-dieser-pc-mit-leerem-bereich-vor-festplattenicon-und-ordner/) this is due to the files on demand feature of OneDrive. so here Microsoft shows if a file is locally located or not. and this overlay icon needs some space to show. But they haven't found how to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the website at the link shared above (thanks @magicandre1981), you can restore the DLL from an older version to remove the space: [German page](https://www.deskmodder.de/blog/2017/12/10/dieser-pc-festplatten-und-ordnericons-wieder-an-den-rand-setzen/), and [Proof it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaxhA.png)

I translated the steps to English with Google Translate and fixed the grammar:

1. Download the [zip containing ExplorerFrame.dll](https://www.deskmodder.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/explorerframedll-windows-10-1703.zip) and unzip
2. Go to C:\Windows\System32 in File Explorer and take ownership of ExplorerFrame.dll, then rename it to ExplorerFrame.dll.backup
3. Now copy the dll from the unzipped folder into the System32 folder. Windows 10 x64 users use the one in the 64 bit folder, Windows 10 32 (x86) users use the one in the 32 bit folder.
   *Windows 10 x64 users go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64, same process and then copy the dll from the 32-bit folder into it.*
4. Right-click in the taskbar, open Task Manager, go to details and kill all explorer.exe processes (if you have multiple) then click File, Run then explorer.exe.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea

Comment: Of course do this at your own risk, and make backups. But if you want to get rid of the space bad enough...